# Vertica Compare table content

Tags: sql, vertica

I have the following two tables in Vertica with column names A, B, C, D. I've listed the row values below

```
Table 1

100, Active, R, 80
200, Inactive, R, 20
300, Active, V, 50
500, Active, R, 30

Table 2

100, Active, R, 80
200, Inactive, R, 20
300, Inactive, V, 50
400, Inactive, R, 60
```

I'd like to compare these two tables and only print the rows which are different between these two tables and rows which are present in one, but not in the other table. I tried the following SQL, which works for one scenario ( It's able to provide the rows which are present in one and not in the other, but it's not able to )

```
select * from (select A,B,C,D from Table1 except select A,B,C,D from Table2) "T" union all select * from (A,B,C,D from Table2 except select A,B,C,D from Table1) "T";

300, Active, V, 50
300, Inactive, V, 50
500, Active, R, 30
400, Inactive, R, 60
```

But I'd like to have only one row when there the same row is present in both tables with different values:

```
300, Inactive, V, 50
500, Active, R, 30
400, Inactive, R, 60
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by row, you mean "A" value.

Assuming no duplicates in either table, you can use aggregation:

```
select a
from ((select 1 as which, a, b, c, d from t1) union all
      (select 2 as which, a, b, c, d from t2)
     ) t
group by a
having min(b) <> max(b) or min(c) <> max(c) or min(d) <> max(d);
```

You can add additional columns, depending on what information you really want.  Also, this ignores `NULL` values.  The logic just a bit more cumbersome to handle `NULL`s as well.

Comment: Hi Gordon, these two tables are ideally supposed to have the same data. But in reality there might be few differences. The objective is to pick the differences between these two tables and present them. The query I have is able to present the differences, but it presents both the records from each of the tables if there is a difference in values. I'd like to select just one of those records. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rahul . . . And this answer does not do what you want?